# How to set code for a particular page width in php bootstrap

Tags: php, wordpress, width

I am trying to develop a unique layout for my posts in my `Wordpress theme` for mobile devices. I am not sure how I should refer to a certain page width in `PHP`.

I have come up with the following code but it does not seem to work.

```
<?php if( (width == 320) && has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
.
.
.
} else {
.
.
.
}
```

Please let me know your ideas.
Regards

Comment: You can't, PHP is a server side language. It can't know the width of the persons device. You need to use JavaScript and CSS for responsiveness.

Comment: Thanks Styphon. So I need to look for such a snippet as I am not good at Java at all.

Comment: Java is not the same as JavaScript.